# NoMethodError undefined method `configure' for #<Sinatra::Application>

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I tried to work sinatra application, but the error occurs which is very mystery.

[image: Error Screen]

```
#encoding: utf-8
require 'sinatra'
require 'rss'
require 'dalli'
require './url'
require './feed'

set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

configure :production do
    require 'newrelic_rpm'
end

...

configure :development do
  require 'sinatra/reloader'
end

...

get '/new_movie' do
  if params['tag2']
    @key = 'tag1=' + params['tag1'] + '&tag2=' + params['tag2']
  else
    @key = 'tag1=' + params['tag1']
  end

  configure :production do ####### ERROR OCCURS AT HERE! #######
    # if cache exists
    if output = settings.cache.get(@key)
      @isCacheUsed = true
      output
    end
  end

  unless @isCacheUsed
    # Thread One
    t1 = Thread.new(params['tag1']) do |param_tag1|
      @feed_nico = feed_nico(param_tag1)
      puts 'nico' if DEBUG_APP
    end
    # Thread Two
    if params['tag2']
      t2 = Thread.new(params['tag2']) do |param_tag2|
        @feed_vimeo = feed_vimeo(param_tag2)
        puts 'vimeo' if DEBUG_APP
      end
    end
    # Main Thread
    feed_hatena1 = feed_hatena(params['tag1'])
    puts 'hatena1' if DEBUG_APP

    t1.join
    t2.join if params['tag2']

    if params['tag2']
      feed = feed_hatena1.append(
        @feed_nico, @feed_vimeo).
        unique
      puts 'append + unique' if DEBUG_APP
    else
      feed = feed_hatena1.append(@feed_nico).unique
    end

    content_type = 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
    @output = feed.to_s
  end
end

...
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you will do something like `if output = settings.cache.get(@key) && settings.production?` instead of  `configure :production do`

Answer (score 1):

You can't call "configure" from within your route. Make sure that all your configuration parameters exist outside of your routes